# Where I can find php_sqlite.dll binary for Windows and PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, sqlite, dll, pdo

I need to work with a legacy SQLite 2 database in PHP 5.4 on Windows x64 using the PDO extension. While the `php_sqlite.dll` is available for PHP 5.3, [it has been removed in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php):

> Since PHP 5.0 this extension was bundled with PHP. Beginning with PHP
>   5.4, this extension is available only via PECL.
>
> Windows users must enable php_sqlite.dll inside of php.ini in order to
>   use these functions. A DLL for this PECL extension is currently
>   unavailable. See also the building on Windows section.

I should [compile it by myself](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php) but I'm not sure if I can. Do you know if compiled binaries exists?

Comment: I do not see any official RC for this particular dll extension. I would suggest compiling =). You definitely can, follow the instructions on that page. Make a backup of your data before hand just to be safe.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I managed to compile it but still I can't use PDO with SQLite 2 (I'm only able to use sqlite_* old funcitons). Have you any idea how to enable sqlite2 support in PDO? See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879265/compiled-php-sqlite-for-php-5-4-pdo-still-cant-find-the-driver-with-dns-sqlite